# Longitudinal wave, crest and the trough of a transverse wave correspond

Tags: waves

Which areas of a longitudinal wave do the crest and the trough of a transverse wave correspond to?

Comment: Typically, the compression corresponds to a crest and the rarefaction corresponds to a trough.